# How to destroy $scope value on stateChange?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `$stateChangeStart` event trigger whenever user navigate between the templates, so in below code when user change a state i am deleting `$scope.filename` that is working as expected but when i go back to that page its throwing a exception and i lose socket.io connection because `$scope.filename` value is still there that is executing if statement. How can i destroy $scope value in this case ?

ctrl.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').controller('DitCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, DitFactory, FileSaver, Blob, socket, $uibModal, searchFactory) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.event = [];
    $scope.disabledRecBtn = false;
    $scope.disabledStopBtn = true;
    $scope.showMessage = false;
    var totalCurrentBytes = [];
    $scope.curVal = 4000;
    $scope.maxVal = 37737;

    //ENDS HERE
    var sendMessageFlag = false;
    // Delete File method
    function deleteFile(filename) {
        DitFactory.getFile(filename).then(function(response, $window) {
            console.log('data for download', response);
            var data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            var blob = new Blob([data], {
                type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
            });
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'server.log');
            socket.emit('stopRecording', $scope.filename);
        });
    }
    socket.on('ditConsumer', function(data) {
        var obj = {
            file: $scope.filename,
            data: data
        }
        $scope.event.push(data);
        jsonToArray();
        socket.emit('messageToFile', obj);
        if (sendMessageFlag === true) {
            return sendMessageToFile(obj);
        }
    });

    function sendMessageToFile(data) {
        if (data.file) {
            socket.emit('startrecording', data);
            $scope.disabledRecBtn = true;
            $scope.disabledStopBtn = false;
            $scope.showMessage = true;
        }
    }
    $scope.stopLogs = function() {
        sendMessageFlag = false;
        $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/web/global/modal.html',
            controller: 'ModalController'
        });
    };
    $rootScope.$on('downloadFile', function(s, data) {
        deleteFile($scope.filename);
        $scope.disabledRecBtn = false;
        $scope.disabledStopBtn = true;
        $scope.showMessage = false;
    });
    $rootScope.$on('onCancelDelete', function() {
        if ($scope.filename) {
            console.log('oncanceldelete function');
            socket.emit('stopRecording', $scope.filename);
            $scope.disabledRecBtn = false;
            $scope.disabledStopBtn = true;
            $scope.showMessage = false;
        }
    });
    $scope.recordLogs = function() {
        socket.emit('createlogfile');
        socket.on('filename', function(filename) {
            console.log('filename from sever', filename);
            $scope.filename = filename;
            sendMessageFlag = true;
            $scope.disabledRecBtn = true;
            $scope.disabledStopBtn = false;
            $scope.showMessage = true;
        });
    }

    //Search logs code here
    $scope.searchLogs = function() {
        $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/view/modals/searchModal.html',
            controller: 'SearchController'
        });
        searchFactory.setDitLogs($scope.event);
    }
    $scope.serverFiles = function() {
        $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: '/view/modals/serverModal.html',
            controller: 'ServerFilesCtrl'
        })
    }

      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
           function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
               if($scope.filename) {
                   console.log($scope.filename);
                   console.log('STATE CHANGED');
                   console.log('destroy on close');
                   socket.emit('stopRecording', $scope.filename);
                   sendMessageFlag = false;
                   $scope.filename = null;
               }
           })
});
```

Comment: `$scope.filename = null`?

Comment: where you define the `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart)` callback?

Comment: i did not defined callback anywhere

Answer (score 0):

All the scopes are destroyed when a routing is done. That is the feature that ui- router comes with. If you want to manually specify it for a certain purpose you can always use $scope.$destroy for certain controllers.

Comment: When i change state and go back to previous one i still see `$scope.filename` value i am using ui-router , As you mentioned ui-router comes with that feature then why still see the value ?

Comment: When you add the listener to the $rootScope and when you navigate away from a controller, the listener remains and keeps triggering. Hence you need to destroy manually. You might want to share full code snipped to controller in order to help better.

Comment: Also when i go back to state all methods are invoking twice e.g `$scope.recordLogs` printing `console.log('filename from sever', filename);` twice is it related issue ?

Comment: You should not listen on $rootScope as I said earlier they dont get destroyed. You need to unbind them. Please change all listeners to listen on $scope.

Comment: when i use $scope.$on i can not listen from  `$rootScope.$emit('downloadFile')`

Comment: @hussain Use `$RootScope.$broadcast('downloadFile')` to send AngularJS notification from `$rootScope` to a child `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

> when i go back to state all methods are invoking twice e.g `$scope.recordLogs` printing `console.log('filename from sever', filename);`

The `console.log` is part of the handler function that has been given to the `socket` service. Even though the `$scope` has been destroyed, the `socket.on` handler function has been saved by the `socket` service.

```
   $scope.recordLogs = function() {
        socket.emit('createlogfile');
        //PROBLEM
        //event handler function retained by socket service
        socket.on('filename', function(filename) {
            console.log('filename from sever', filename);
            $scope.filename = filename;
            sendMessageFlag = true;
            $scope.disabledRecBtn = true;
            $scope.disabledStopBtn = false;
            $scope.showMessage = true;
        });
    }
```

To avoid duplicating event handlers when a user navigates back and forth between routes use `socket.forward`:

```
angular.module('myMod', ['btford.socket-io']).
  controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, socket) {
    socket.forward('someEvent', $scope);
    $scope.$on('socket:someEvent', function (ev, data) {
      $scope.theData = data;
    });
  });
```

By using `socket.forward`, the `socket` service will unregister the handler when the `$scope` gets destroyed.

For more information, see [angular-socket-io API Reference - socket.forward](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io#socketforward)